Ubuntu NUMA memory policy
So far I was known that there are two types of NUMA memory policies which are "per task/process" and "Per memory region". As per below numa_map entry, I have few queries. Can you please make me understanding. Thanks in advance.
077d1000 default file=/usr/bin/bash anon=69 dirty=224 mapmax=3 active=155 N0=69 N1=155 kernelpagesize_kB=4
7ffe2d5cb000 default stack anon=27 dirty=27 active=1 N0=27 kernelpagesize_kB=4
7ffe2d5fa000 default
7ffe2d5fe000 default

1.) How can I know which policy applied for this /usr/bin/bash?
2.) As per the entry, how many pages are allocated to this process? 69+155 = 224 of N0 and N1? or all values of 69 + 224 + 3 + 155 + 69 + 155 = 675 ?
3.) What is 077d1000 ? Is it memory range starts for the entry above ?
4.) How NUMA determines which policy be applied for tasks // memory regions ?
5.) The process spanned on both N0 and N1 nodes. It indicates it is interleave or memory was not available on one node and allocated on different node(numa_miss)?

